# Regular Expression: Remove the middle string

Tags: regex

I have the following sentence:

```
**     DATE : 04/12/2014   * TIME: 07:49:42                **
```

I only want to capture `04/12/2014 07:49:42.`

I've tried this `.*DATE : ([0-9\/]+.*TIME: [0-9\:]+)`

But I got this: `"04/12/2014   * TIME: 07:49:42."`

How can I remove `"   * TIME:"?`

I need it in pure regex, so I'm testing at http://www.regexr.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[\* ]*Date\s*:\s*([0-9/]+)[ \*]*time\s*:\s*([0-9:]+)[ \*]*
```

in replace statement u use `$1 $2` then you will get what you want

Comment: Is it possible to solve it in the same capture group?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
/\*\* +DATE : ([\d|\/]+) +\* TIME: ([\d|:]+) +\*\*/
```

This will return a tuple. So, for example, using JavaScript:

```
var s = "**     DATE : 04/12/2014   * TIME: 07:49:42                **",
    re = /\*\* +DATE : ([\d|\/]+) +\* TIME: ([\d|:]+) +\*\*/;

re.exec(s);  // returns ["original string", "04/12/2014", "07:49:42"]
```

**breakdown**:

`\*\* +DATE :` (note the space after the colon) matches up to `"DATE : "`

`([\d|\/]+)` matches numbers and slashes and captures them as the first group.

`+\* TIME:` matches up to `"TIME: "`

`([\d|:]+)` captures the time by matching numbers or colons

`+\*\*/` finishes off the sequence

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
/DATE\s+:\s+([0-9/]+).+TIME\s+:\s+([0-9:]+)/
```